# Как правильно сделать запрос на mysql через nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
let first_name = req.body.first_name;
let last_name = req.body.last_name;
let number = req.body.number;
let auto = req.body.auto;
let info = req.body.info;
let price = req.body.price;

let usernameQuery = "SELECT * FROM `ann` WHERE first_name = '" + first_name + "'";
db.query("INSERT INTO `ann` (first_name, last_name, number, info, price, auto) VALUES ('" + first_name + "', '" + last_name + "', '" + number + "', '" + info + "', '" + price + "', '" + auto + "')", function(err, info) {
  console.log(info.insertId);
});
```

В базе данных после отправки запроса в полях появляются `undefined`.

Comment: Если у вас в полях undefined, значит вы не передаете данные и у вас first_name и остальные поля остаются неопределенными, дело не в sql-запросе, а в req.body, проверьте, что в них есть данные.

Comment: Sergey Glazirin, Можно поподробнее?

Comment: Добавьте console.log(req.body.first_name) после первой строки и посмотрите, что там будет, если undefined, то скорее всего у вас данные не приходят в http-запросе

Comment: [пример](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=mysql+query+node+js)